# project build error: 'dependencies.dependencies.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:jar is missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using Springboot version 2.6.5. I'm getting below  error when i add below dependencies. I'm using java version 1.8 and spring-cloud-version Greenwich.SR2

project build error: 'dependencies.dependencies.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:jar is missing

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
          </exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jercy-client</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jercy-core</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jercy-apache-client4</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Those versions are incompatible. Please use spring cloud version 2021.0.1

Comment: @spencergibb what's the compatible spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client version for Springboot version 2.6.5. Even if i change the spring cloud version to 2021.0.1 netflix-eureka-client showing error.

Comment: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/3.1.2